# React Native issue with I18n in an array of object

Tags: javascript, react-native, internationalization, i18n-js

I use I18n in my app with a config :

```
 I18n.translations = {
    en: en,
    fr: fr,
  };

  if (!__DEV__) {
    I18n.fallbacks = true;
  }

  I18n.defaultLocale = 'en';
  I18n.locale = localeLanguageTag as ELanguagesKeys;
```

Then I export it and use it as usual ...

In a component, I have an object array with some translation key :

```
const onBordingSteps: ISteps = [
    {
      label: I18n.t('auth.heading.steps.onboarding.step1.title'),
      isCompleted: true,
      icon: GGValidation,
      iconHeight: 49.36,
      iconWidth: 28.48,
    },
    {
      label: I18n.t('auth.heading.steps.onboarding.step2.title'),
      isCompleted: false,
      .....
  ];
```

I use this array directly after its creation in my component

```
return (
    <PreOnboarding
      steps={onBordingSteps}
    ...
```

But when I import this array from another file, it didn't find the key and I have this error on each items:

[image]
I don't understand why ... an idea?

Comment: Could you please share how your keys look like? I just took a look at my own setup which works and the only thing I can think of is that maybe the issue is how those keys are stored

Comment: @dianaqqq the key file is just an object in a js file. 
I'm not sure because when I declare the same array above the component, I got it ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you, because I think it might be an issue with the export method of the keys since they cannot be found

In my implementation I store the keys like this

1. I have a js/ts file, called Strings where I store the keys

```js
import { translate } from "./I18n"

const Strings = {
  SOME_WORD: translate("keyName.firstWord"),
  ANOTHER_WORD:  translate("keyName.firstWord")
  ...
 }
```

2. In my l18n file I defined a `translate` function (in this way you won't have to import the `i18n-js` wherever you use it

```js
import * as RNLocalize from "react-native-localize"
import i18n from "i18n-js"

import en from "./en"

const translations = { en }

const { languageTag } = RNLocalize.findBestAvailableLanguage(Object.keys(translations)) || {
  languageTag: "en",
}

i18n.locale = languageTag
i18n.fallbacks = true
i18n.translations = translations

export function translate(key: string) {
  return key ? i18n.t(key) : ""
}

export default i18n
```

3. In a separate file, called en.ts I have the actual translations

```js
export default {
  keyName: {
    firstWord: "The actual translation",
    ...
    
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your proposition.
I tried with a function like "translate" but it doesn't work and as I'm in expo project and can't use react-native-localize

Comment: I understand. However, you don't need that part for implementing the translate function, that's only for setting the locale, thing which you already did (here `I18n.defaultLocale = 'en'`)